# Paginate on category does not work with Transcribe

Tags: channel-entries, add-on, ee3, pagination, transcribe

I've got a simple entries tag with category option and a paginate tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="download" category="12" limit="5"}
...
{paginate}
```

**But the paginate tag does not work: it is not processed.**

I'm using [Transcribe](https://eeharbor.com/transcribe) Add-on and after a while my understanding is: this Add-on cause the issue. If I add **transcribe="disable"** to **channel:entries** tag the paginate is displayed and everything works as I expected.

I have found out that other users had this problem years ago with Transcribe Add-on. This problem still persists on the latest versions of EE3 and the Transcribe Add-on.

I wonder if someone may have found a solution and if all these problems with a commercial Add-on and if they are acceptable. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Same thing happens with me. It removes `pagination` from exp channel entries. No pagination link ever display at bottom neither pagination working